# SQL: find customers who own accounts in all of the branches that 'Adam Rivera' owns accounts in

Tags: sql

I need To find The Customer ID,  last name and birth dates of customers who own accounts in **All of the branches** that Adam Rivera owns accounts in.

This is the bank schema:

```
§ Customer = {customerID, firstName, lastName, income, birthDate }
§ Account = {accNumber, type, balance, branchNumberFK-Branch}
§ Owns = {customerIDFK-Customer, accNumberFK-Account}
§ Transactions = {transNumber, accNumberFK-Account, amount}
§ Employee = {sin, firstName, lastName, salary, branchNumberFK-Branch}
§ Branch = {branchNumber, branchName, managerSINFK-Employee, budget}
```

**All branch numbers that Adam Rivera owns**, The query gives:

```
branchNumber
1
4

SELECT b2.branchNumber -- all branches that Adam Rivera owns
FROM Customer c2 join Owns o2 on c2.customerID = o2.customerID join Account a2 on a2.accNumber = o2.accNumber join Branch b2 on b2.branchNumber = a2.branchNumber
WHERE c2.firstName = 'Adam' and c2.lastName = 'Rivera'
```

**A list of branch numbers that a customer has an account at Adam Rivera's branches**, The reuslt is :

```
cusID   lstName birthDate   branch#
10839   Hayes   1977-06-09  1
10839   Hayes   1977-06-09  4
11790   Green   1920-11-19  1
11790   Green   1920-11-19  1
13230   Brooks  1967-05-04  1
13423   Simmons 1955-03-21  1
13423   Simmons 1955-03-21  4
13697   Hill    1951-03-07  1
13697   Hill    1951-03-07  4
14295   Ramirez 1983-06-30  4
18166   Barnes  1951-03-07  1
19973   Kelly   1987-07-15  1
22050   Sanchez 1935-01-08  1
.......


SELECT c1.customerID, c1.lastName, c1.birthDate, b1.branchNumber

FROM Customer c1 join Owns o1 on c1.customerID = o1.customerID join Account a1 on a1.accNumber = o1.accNumber join Branch b1 on b1.branchNumber = a1.branchNumber

WHERE EXISTS 
      SELECT b3.branchNumber
      FROM Customer c3 join Owns o3 on c3.customerID = o3.customerID join Account a3 on a3.accNumber = o3.accNumber join Branch b3 on b3.branchNumber = a3.branchNumber
      WHERE c3.firstName = 'Adam' and c3.lastName = 'Rivera' and b1.branchNumber = b3.branchNumber
```

The following result should return all of the branches that a customer does not have an account at, if the customer has an account at every branch then this result is empty.

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (branch numbers that Adam Rivera owns) 
    EXCEPT 
    (a list of branch numbers that a customer has account at Adam Rivera's branches)
```

Using NOT EXIST after WHERE, should return a customer who owns **all** Adam Rivera's account

This is the query I wrote.

```
SELECT c1.customerID, c1.lastName, c1.birthDate

FROM Customer c1 join Owns o1 on c1.customerID = o1.customerID join Account 
a1 on a1.accNumber = o1.accNumber join Branch b1 on b1.branchNumber = 
a1.branchNumber

WHERE NOT EXISTS

  (-- all branch numbers that Adam Rivera owns
  (SELECT b2.branchNumber 
  FROM Customer c2 join Owns o2 on c2.customerID = o2.customerID join 
Account a2 on a2.accNumber = o2.accNumber join Branch b2 on b2.branchNumber = a2.branchNumber
  WHERE c2.firstName = 'Adam' and c2.lastName = 'Rivera') 

  EXCEPT

  -- a list of branch numbers that a customer has account at Adam Rivera's branches
  (SELECT b3.branchNumber 
  FROM (Customer c3 join Owns o3 on c3.customerID = o3.customerID join Account a3 on a3.accNumber = o3.accNumber join Branch b3 on b3.branchNumber = a3.branchNumber)
  WHERE c3.firstName = 'Adam' and c3.lastName = 'Rivera' and b1.branchNumber = b3.branchNumber )
  )
```

The query should return Hayes, Simmons, Hill. But the result returns nothing(error). I can not figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
with ar as (
      select distinct a.branchNumber
      from Customer c join
           Owns o 
           on c.customerID = o.customerID join
           Account a
           on a.accNumber = o.accNumber 
      where c.firstName = 'Adam' and c.lastName = 'Rivera'
     )
select o.customerId
from Owns o 
     Account a
     on a.accNumber = o.accNumber join
     ar
     on ar.branchNumber = a.branchNumber
group by o.customerId
having count(distinct a.branchNumber) = (select count(*) from ar);
```

The subquery are the accounts that Mr. Rivera owns.  The `join` matches each account.  The `group by` and `having` count the number of distinct branches for each customer, and check that the number matches Mr. Rivera's number.